# How to use createIndex with Loopback 4 mongodb connector for geolocation storage?

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

I am not sure where and how I can call `createIndex` or `ensureIndex` to ensure I have `2dsphere` indexing on the associated mongo database upon application boot. Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **enableGeoIndexing** Set to **true** to enable 2d sphere indexing for model properties of type GeoPoint.

check https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/MongoDB-connector.html#installation additional property section.